# How to purchase the digital content in iOS eBooks app?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, in-app-purchase, payment

I'm going to make an iOS app which is similiar to iBooks, alongside a webserver on which we can manage contents.

The BIG question is "how do we implement books purchases in iOS app"

Here are the possible answers(I could figure out so far) to above question but couldn't find a smart and good solution though.

**1) iBooks is great but no way to mimic...**

We could find out that iBooks is an app without IAP in AppStore but the experience of books purhcasing is like purchasing an IAP item.

How can we do this?

**2) Adding IAP items to itunes connect.**

When a new book is came out we need to add a new IAP item in itunes connect?

Can we automate this on my webserver?

Following apps seem to be adding IAP items - do they manage to do this manually?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/la-biblia-reina-valera-estudio/id519625336?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/qq-yue-du/id487608658?l=en&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

**3) Adding an IAP item per each price Tier.**

We pre-add consumable IAP items for price Tiers(one item per one Tier) and we hold apple id of purchaser and book purchased on our own server.

But in this case we need to get apple id which is quite impossible.

**4) Own User DB on Our Own Server**

We create own user database on our own server. We can apply the idea of #3 but it should be very inconvenient for users to login twice - one for apple id and one for login to our own db.

Is there any solution which'd work great as iBooks does?